# Roll up daily data into monthly buckets in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Having trouble figuring out what seems like it should be a basic use case. Given a table of data written daily ('activity_date' date NOT NULL), roll up data into monthly buckets. GROUP BY [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and Date Type [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) aren't much help and I can't find any tutorials on Google. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579803/group-mysql-data-into-arbitrarily-sized-time-buckets) but I can't figure out how to make it work for my case. Is there a simple way to get what I need?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Sum up everything in a given month? Show one record per month? Show only one month of data?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, that's exactly what I need. I accepted the answer with the earliest time stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about grouping by year and month?

```
SELECT YEAR(activity_date), MONTH(activity_date), COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(activity_date), MONTH(activity_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions are probably what you are looking for.  that is if you want different aggregated data for each distinct month (just using `MONTH` without year would group date by month across years).  So something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(activity_date) as `year`, MONTH(activity_date) as `month`, [other fields with aggregation functions]
FROM table
GROUP BY `year`, `month`
ORDER BY `year`, `month`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions inside the GROUP BY clause, such as `MONTH()`

```
GROUP BY YEAR(activity_date), MONTH(activity_date)
```